How to write CSV Output for Max Coverage Location Optimization R Script?
I'm currently working on a script to solve a maximum coverage location optimization problem. While the script appears to be functioning correctly, I'm struggling with the output format in CSV. I'm unable to clearly identify which hubs have been selected to be open ('1' for open, '0' for not open) in the output file. Additionally, I'm having trouble marking which demand points are covered ('1' for covered, '0' for not covered) by these hubs.
Could someone please assist me in modifying my script to clearly output these details into a CSV file? Any guidance on structuring the CSV output to include binary indicators for open hubs and covered demands would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

# Define data and model as previously set up
demand <- c('es1', 'es2', 'es3', 'bs1', 'bs2', 'bs3', 'cs1', 'cs2', 'cs3')
hubs <- c('MHa1', 'MHa2', 'MHb1', 'MHc1')
coverage_matrix <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0,
                            0, 1, 1, 0,
                            0, 0, 0, 1,
                            0, 0, 1, 0,
                            0, 0, 0, 1,
                            1, 0, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 0, 1,
                            0, 0, 0, 1,
                            0, 0, 0, 1),
                          nrow = length(demand), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(demand, hubs))
P <- 2

model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[j], j = hubs, type = "binary") %>%
  add_variable(y[i], i = demand, type = "binary") %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(y[i] * 1, i = demand), "max") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(coverage_matrix[i, j] * x[j], j = hubs) >= y[i], i = demand) %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[j], j = hubs) <= P)

result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = FALSE))

# Extract solutions
solution_x <- get_solution(result, x[j]) %>%
  mutate(hub = as.character(j))

solution_y <- get_solution(result, y[i]) %>%
  mutate(demand_point = as.character(i))
# Initialize a summary table with default values
summary_table <- data.frame(
  id = c(hubs, demand),
  type = c(rep("Hub", length(hubs)), rep("Demand Point", length(demand))),
  status = c(rep("Not Selected", length(hubs)), rep("Not Covered", length(demand)))
)

# Update the summary table with the results for hubs
summary_table$status[summary_table$id %in% solution_x$hub[solution_x$value > 0]] <- "Selected"

# Update the summary table with the results for demand points
summary_table$status[summary_table$id %in% solution_y$demand_point[solution_y$value > 0]] <- "Covered"

# Print the summary table
print(summary_table)

# Save the summary table to a CSV file
write.csv(summary_table, "optimization_results.csv", row.names = FALSE)

I am expecting the results should be like this:
print(summary_table)
     id         type       status
1  MHa1          Hub Not Selected
2  MHa2          Hub Not Selected
3  MHb1          Hub Selected
4  MHc1          Hub Selected
5   es1 Demand Point  Covered
6   es2 Demand Point  Covered
7   es3 Demand Point  Covered
8   bs1 Demand Point  Covered
9   bs2 Demand Point  Covered
10  bs3 Demand Point  Not Covered
11  cs1 Demand Point  Covered
12  cs2 Demand Point  Covered
13  cs3 Demand Point  Covered


I get Error in validate_quantifier_candidates(candidates, zero_vars_msg) :    only_integer_candidates are not all TRUE Calls: %>% ... add_variable_.optimization_model -> validate_quantifier_candidates -> stopifnot
